# How to convert JSON array to JavaScript Array?

Tags: json, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS for data binding.
Following code is controller's action method

```
public JsonResult GetPeople()
{
    var people = new List<Person>
                     {
                         new Person {Name = "aaaa", Address = "aaaaaaaaa"},
                         new Person {Name = "bbbb", Address = "bbbbbbbbb"},
                         new Person {Name = "cccc", Address = "ccccccccc"}
                     };
    return Json(people, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And bellow is the snippet of client side code

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
  <li>NAME:<span data-bind="text: Name"></span></li>
  <li>ADDRESS:<span data-bind="text: Address"></span></li>  
</ul>

<script>
    function getPeopleFromServer() {
        var people= [];

        $.ajax({
            url: "GetPeople",
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("result= " + result);
                people = $.parseJSON(result);
                console.log("people= " + people);
            }
        });

        return people;
    }

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        // data
        self.people = ko.observableArray(getPeopleFromServer());        
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

The problem is that people variable in the getPeopleFromServer method is always null while result has proper value from the server.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you get from console.log("result= " + result);

Comment: Have you checked to see if jQuery is parsing results as JSON for you? You might drop the `$.parseJSON` and see if things start working...

Comment: 'success' is an inline async function.  Basically, 'return people' happens before the 'success' function is called, because the ajax call is non-blocking.  You need to redesign your ViewModel to work  asynchronously (or turn off async), hopefully others will chime in with code fixes

Comment: I have log like this "result= [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
        people= null"

Comment: @Tom regarding redesign viewmodel, what I want is to separate server invoke method from the viewmodel. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: @Ray yeah I'd probably come up with a initPeople() method, which does your server invoke (ajax call), and populates your 'People' property on the callback (kick this off in your 'success' method).  After your viewmodel is fully populated, then you can call .applyBindings or whatever.  Basically, start the process backwards.  That's just one way to do it, hope that makes sense...

Comment: If result prints as [object Object] etc, then it is already a javascript array so there is no need to parseJSON.  However you return the empty people array before the call is complete, why not put the function into your view model and have it update the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tom's comment is correct.

> 'success' is an inline async function. Basically, 'return people' happens before the 'success' function is called, because the ajax call is non-blocking. You need to redesign your ViewModel to work asynchronously (or turn off async), hopefully others will chime in with code fixes

Here's the fully commented fiddle he prophesied.

http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/8Wqum/

Answer (score 1):

Your `$.ajax` function is taking longer to complete than it's containing function, and so the containing function never popuplates `people` by the end of execution

One thing you can do is to add the following to your `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: "GetPeople",
   .....
});
```

`async: false` will make the containing function 'wait' until ajax is finished. Your people var should be populated by the end of function execution. While this is a quick win, I agree with [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882436/tom) that you should re-think how your ViewModel is handled.

Comment: thanks your reply Martin, I added "async: false", but the people is still null while result is not null.

Answer (score 0):

people should be referred to either in the same view model. Or as self.people. I suggest you put the call to ajax inside the view model and then it will be clear.
So getPeopleFromServer() should be inside the viewmodel.

Out of interest you can also add
timeout: 600000 so that the call doesnt timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ko.mapping plugin.

```
function ViewModelWrapper(jsonResult)
{
       var self = this;
       self.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonResult);
}
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html